# Is a final comma necessary when describing a description?

Tags: commas, clauses

Sorry, the title is a bit confusing... basically, which of the following is correct?

Without a comma:

> Cory Doctorow, author of Little Brother, the book you had me read during a camping trip which I loved for its realistic **nature is** quoted here.

With a comma:

> Cory Doctorow, author of Little Brother, the book you had me read during a camping trip which I loved for its realistic **nature, is** quoted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clause beginning with *the book* and ending with *nature* is an interruption to the sentence, and needs to be set off by a **pair** of commas, and so a comma is needed after *nature* to match the one after *Little Brother*.

There’s another point. Is the clause *which I loved for its realistic nature* intended as a defining or non-defining relative clause? I suspect the latter: it provides additional information, and doesn’t define *the book*. If that is the case, then the convention is to set it off by a pair of commas as well. If you accept my view of the clause *the book . . . nature*, there will already be a comma at the end of the relative clause, but a comma after *trip* would show that *which I loved . . .* is to be read as a non-defining relative clause.

My final version, then, would be:

> Cory Doctorow, author of Little Brother, the book you had me read
>   during a camping trip, which I loved for its realistic nature, is
>   quoted here.

Comment: Instead of a comma, you could even add `and` between `trip` and `which`. For me, that removes the possible ambiguity as to whether the book or the trip were loved for their realistic nature.

Comment: @Barrie England - I agree with your grammatical analysis, but in terms of punctuation, would suggest that using em dashes rather than commas around the relative clause to give visual clarity, and make it easier to follow the line of thought, eg 'Cory Doctorow, author of Little Brother— the book you had me read during a camping trip, which I loved for its realistic nature—is quoted here.'

Comment: Perhaps, but the OP was asking about commas.

Comment: @BarrieEngland - agreed that OP is asking about commas, but do *you* think there is comma overload here? I feel that parentheses or dashes would improve the sentence considerably.

Comment: I don't. I have an aversion to dashes, at least in formal writing, and parentheses reduce the significance of their contents in a way which I don't think would be desirable here. There are, of course, all sorts of other ways of expressing the writer's thoughts.